# Check if a json array value exits on php or not

Tags: php, arrays, json

**Hi everyone**

I´m making a project where i need to check if a **'x'** value, which is being defined on a PHP variable, is founded or not inside the JSON **steamid** array...

Here is a example of how JSON structure looks like:

---

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "steamid": "[X:X:XXXXXXXXX]",
        "teamspeakid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "nicknames": [
            "XXXXXXXXX"
        ],
        "addresses": [
            "XX.XX.XXX.XX"
        ]
    },
    {
        "steamid": "[Y:Y:YYYYYYYYY]",
        "teamspeakid": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
        "nicknames": [
            "YYYYYYYYY"
        ],
        "addresses": [
            "YY.YY.YYY.YY"
        ]
    },
    {
        "steamid": "[Z:Z:ZZZZZZZZZ]",
        "teamspeakid": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
        "nicknames": [
            "ZZZZZZZZZ"
        ],
        "addresses": [
            "ZZ.ZZ.ZZZ.ZZ"
        ]
    }

]}
```

The PHP function structure that I have on my mind is similar to this:

---

```
if (x value is founded on json->users steamid array) {

   $verified = 1;
   $teamspeakid = the founded steamid->teamspeakid;
   $nicknames = the founded steamid->nicknames;
   $addresses = the founded steamid->addresses;

} elseif (steamid value is not founded on json array) {

   $verified = 0;

}
```

**I hope you can help me :-)**

Comment: steamid doesn't look as an array, you want to look for substring inside string?

Comment: @Robert Yes :-)

Comment: so do foreach + strpos() or preg_match :)

Comment: @Robert I have tried this before... `foreach ($json->users as $key => $users) {
  if ($users->steamid == $steamid3) {
   echo '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="xxx.php">Panel de control »</a>';
   break;
  }else{
   require __DIR__ . "xxx.php";
   break;
  }
 }` But it doesn´t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the json array then use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check the string or character exists or not.Do like below:

```
$jsonarr='{
"users": [
    {
        "steamid": "[X:X:XXXXXXXXX]",
        "teamspeakid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "nicknames": [
            "XXXXXXXXX"
        ],
        "addresses": [
            "XX.XX.XXX.XX"
        ]
    },
    {
        "steamid": "[Y:Y:YYYYYYYYY]",
        "teamspeakid": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
        "nicknames": [
            "YYYYYYYYY"
        ],
        "addresses": [
            "YY.YY.YYY.YY"
        ]
    },
    {
        "steamid": "[Z:Z:ZZZZZZZZZ]",
        "teamspeakid": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
        "nicknames": [
            "ZZZZZZZZZ"
        ],
        "addresses": [
            "ZZ.ZZ.ZZZ.ZZ"
        ]
    }

]}';

$arr=json_decode($jsonarr,true);
$searchstring='X';
foreach($arr['users'] as $key=>$value){
    if (strpos($value['steamid'], $searchstring) !== false) {
        $verified = 1;
    }else{
        $verified = 0;
    }
}
```

or

```
if(array_search($searchstring, array_column($arr['users'], 'steamid')!== false) {
    $verified = 1;
}else{
    $verified = 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try this? @Alex

Comment: Because of some reason if i search [Y:Y:YYYYYYYYY], I get the 0 value...

Comment: That is in the loop..you will get 0 for first then you will get 1 and then 0

Comment: so what can i do for that?¿